# Access Make table with memo field as column output instead of Text

Tags: ms-access, vba

The Access make table below does the following:

Final app number 10 has three sub apps 6, 7 ,8 in AppCombinedAreasandRegions. Their FirstOfRegion (Memo Field) respectively are "a","b","c". Based on the make table, the ConcatRelated function will create a row in the output table as follows.

**Project Application:** 10
**Region_list:** "a,b,c"

Currently I have this part working.

The issue is the output table stores Region_List ("a,b,c") as a TEXT field, meaning there is a limit and the value from the ConcatRelated function gets truncated. Since the source is a memo field, there will be cases where it exceeds the 255 character limit.

Is there a way for Region_List to be a memo field instead of a text field when using the ConcatRelated function to get the concatenated output?

[image]

Comment: Instead of MAKE TABLE, maybe create the table as a permanent object then DELETE and INSERT records. This is a 'temp' table.

Comment: @June7 Thanks for the reponse! I tried that. Although the field remains as a memo field, the output table still has the result cut to 255 characters, eventhough the output of the function is beyond that.

Comment: I have never tried the function with memo type field. Could be a limitation of that type. I avoid memo type whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to append to the existing table (clearing it first), and setting the concatRelated column from Group By to Expression.